# Okay, so I am reinstalling Ubuntu a 2nd time on the same laptop

Tags: usb-installation

Whenever I try to load from my Ubuntu USB, it takes me to the grub menu with this message:

Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

I have disabled secure boot in bios as well. How do I boot to Ubuntu setup? I have never encountered something like this before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your Ubuntu installation USB is broken. There can be two reasons. First, the ISO file you downloaded was corrupt or incomplete. Second the USB flash drive is defective. For the first problem verify the integrity of the ISO file using the methods described in the official Ubuntu site.

Comment: @user68186 I have installed Ubuntu once before, then I reinstalled windows 10 from a USB. Would this cause any problems with trying to install Ubuntu a 2nd time? I also have checked that my iso is ok.

Comment: I don't think that should be a problem. The symptoms you describes point to a corrupted `grub` in the USB. It has nothing to do with the laptop's hard disk. In any case, did you erase everything (particularly Ubuntu) when you reinstalled Windows?

Comment: For the best results all tutorials say the same Windows FIRST then Ubuntu. Windows does not play well with others.

Comment: And how did you reinstall Windows? If UEFI system, did you install in UEFI boot mode & make sure fast startup is off? And then boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI boot mode? Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012, so only very old hardware is BIOS. Many hardware vendors still call UEFI as BIOS, but it is UEFI.

Comment: @oldfred I just used the media creation tool to reinstall windows and remove Ubuntu.

Comment: @David I just want to get Ubuntu back up and running even if that means I have to uninstall windows.

Comment: @user68186 When I reinstalled windows I selected for it to erase everything then install windows.

Comment: How you booted Windows install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. If you use BIOS, it typically erases Linux partitions from partition table, but often partition is still there. If previous install was UEFI and you installed in BIOS mode or vice-versa the converion from gpt to MBR totally erases drive. From live installer post this `sudo parted -l` in question above to preserve format.